# XML : faxterxml can't deserialize xml element with ignoring xml attribute

Tags: java, xml, fasterxml

I'm trying to deserialize XML with fasterxml library and I encounter an error during the parsing of the xml attribute as below.

the bean :

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Data
public class Product {
    public int id;
    public int id_manufacturer;
}
```

the xml :

```
<product>
   <id><![CDATA[1]]></id>
   <id_manufacturer xlink:href="http://localhost:8080/api/manufacturers/1"><![CDATA[1]]></id_manufacturer>
</product>
```

the dependency :

```
implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat', name: 'jackson-dataformat-xml', version: '2.7.4'
```

the execution :

```
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
xmlMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
System.out.println(xmlMapper.readValue(XML_STRING, Product.class));
```

the exception :

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `int` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)
 at [Source: (File); line: 4, column: 81] (through reference chain: come.has.you.are.Product["id_manufacturer"])
```

Any ideas ?
Of course, I've tried the annotation `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)`

Answer (score -1):

Here is your problem:
`CDATA` is a `String` value, not an `int` value.
Note: CDATA is short for "Character Data".

Option 1: Change your `Product` class.  For example,

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Data
public class Product2
{
    public String id;
    public String id_manufacturer;
}
```

Option 2: Add String setters

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Data
public class Product
{
    public int id;
    
    @JsonProperty("id_manufacturer")
    public int idManufacturer;
    
    public void setId(final String value)
    {
        if (StringUtils.isNumeric(value))
        {
            id = Integer.valueOf(value).intValue();
        } 
    }
    
    public void setIdManufacturer(final String value)
    {
        if (StringUtils.isNumeric(value))
        {
            idManufacturer = Integer.valueOf(value).intValue();
        }
    } 
}
```

Note: `id_manufacturer` is a tag name,
but is not a java field name.

Comment: Option n°2 could not be conceivable because of code maintainability issue.

Option n°1 doesn't answer to the problem. As you can see in the Exception message, it's the id_manufacturer xml element which is not parsable. CDATA and int value doesn't cause error for the id xml element.